# Can an indexed type map be expanded into a discriminated union?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following type map:

```
type MyTypes = {
  'float': number;
  'text': string;
  'bool': boolean;
  'price': number;
  'date': Date;
};
```

And I want to automatically generate a discriminated union type for that. The equivalent of this:

```
type Datum<K, V> = { type: K, value: V };

type MagicUnionMaker<TypeMap> = (
  // pretend the below is auto-generated from TypeMap
  Datum<'float', number> |
  Datum<'text', string> |
  Datum<'bool', boolean> |
  Datum<'price', number> |
  Datum<'date', Date>
);
```

Which could be used like so:

```
interface DataModel<TypeMap> {
  data(row: number, col: number): MagicUnionMaker<TypeMap>;
}

let model: DataModel<MyTypes>;
let datum = model.data(0, 0);
switch (datum.type) {
  case 'float':
    // datum.value is `number`
    break;
  case 'text':
    // datum.value is `string`
    break;
  case 'bool':
    // datum.value is `boolean`
    break;
  case 'price':
    // datum.value is `price`
    break;
  case 'date':
    // datum.value is `Date`
    break;
  case 'thing': // error
    break; 
}
```

Is something like this currently possible?

Comment: AFAIK mapping to a union is not available (yet). I guess the union part have to be written by human.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite, it appears you can't have generic UnionMaker, and need to construct the union type in-place every time you need it:

```
type MyTypes = {
  'float': number;
  'text': string;
  'bool': boolean;
  'price': number;
  'date': Date;
};

type TypeDataMap<T> = {[K in keyof T]: {type: K, value: T[K]}};

interface MyDataModel {
  data(row: number, col: number): TypeDataMap<MyTypes>[keyof MyTypes];
}

let model: MyDataModel;
let datum = model.data(0, 0);
// type inference works as expected 
switch (datum.type) {
  case 'float':
     let n: number = datum.value;
    break;
  case 'text':
     let s: string = datum.value;
    break;
  case 'bool':
    let b: boolean = datum.value;
    break;
  case 'price':
    let p: number = datum.value;
    break;
  case 'date':
     let d: Date = datum.value;
    break;
  case 'thing': // error: Type '"thing"' is not comparable to type 
                // '"float" | "text" | "bool" | "price" | "date"'.
    break; 
}
```

attempt to construct equivalent generic type fails:

```
// does not work
type UnionMaker<T> = TypeDataMap<T>[keyof T]; 

type MyTypeMap = UnionMaker<MyTypes>;
// because MyTypeMap gets inferred for some reason as 
// type MyTypeMap = { 
//     type: "float" | "text" | "bool" | "price" | "date"; 
//     value: string | number | boolean | Date; 
//  }
// which is NOT what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this may be possible in Typescript 2.8, with conditional types, cf. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316

After `npm install`ing `typescript@next` you can do:

```
 type MyTypes = {
    'float': number;
    'text': string;
    'bool': boolean;
    'price': number;
    'date': Date;
 };

 type Datum<K, V> = { t: K, v: V };
 type FromKeys<T, U> = T extends keyof U ? Datum<T, U[T]> : never;
 type UnionMaker2<T, U> = FromKeys<keyof T, U>;
 type UnionMaker<T> = UnionMaker2<T, T>;

 const x1: UnionMaker<MyTypes> = {t: 'text', v: 'string'};
 const x2: UnionMaker<MyTypes> = {t: 'bool', v: true};
 // fails, as expected:
 // const x3: UnionMaker<MyTypes> = {t: 'text', v: true};
```